# Creating html table from array with multiple leves and sub-levels

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to build an html table off of an array with multiple levels/keys and I'm not quite sure how to properly map things after the main loop.

If I dump my array `$RootData` I get:

```
RootData{
    +innerData:array:2[
        "01"=>array:5[
            "name"=>"NAME"
            "number"=>01
            "totals1"=>array:3[
                "sales"=>50
                "returns"=>100
                "total"=>150
            ]
            "totals2"=>array:3[
                "sales"=>50
                "returns"=>100
                "total"=>150
            ]
            "totals3"=>array:3[
                "sales"=>50
                "returns"=>100
                "total"=>150
            ]
        ]
        "02"=>array:5[
            "name"=>"NAME2"
            "number"=>02
            "totals1"=>array:3[
                "sales"=>500
                "returns"=>100
                "total"=>650
            ]
            "totals2"=>array:3[
                "sales"=>500
                "returns"=>100
                "total"=>650
            ]
            "totals3"=>array:3[
                "sales"=>500
                "returns"=>100
                "total"=>650
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Using that, I'm trying to get a table structure like:

```
NAME    | totals1 | totals2 | totals3
-----------------------------------
sales       50        50        50
returns     100       100       100 
total       150       150       150

NAME2    | totals1 | totals2 | totals3
-----------------------------------
sales       500       500       500
returns     100       100       100 
total       650       650       650
```

So I know I can do a

```
@foreach $RootData as $data
    @foreach $data as $key=>value

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Which will give me a result of the inner data, but I want to be able to use the levels inside `innerData` as my table row loop, as you can see above. How can I properly key this array to achieve that with multiple levels? Would I just need to assign a key for each main level?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: you can create a recursive function that processes one level and gives the next levels to be processed to the same function.